# When confirming a post, why not show the page as it will be?

Tags: feature-request, ask-question-form

When I write a post I *rarely* bother to look it over before confirming I want to post it. The reason is purely because I very much prefer to see it in the actual page as it will be and then just edit if I see an error.

I assume there are two reasons for making people review their post. Primarily, to encourage them to fix their errors. Secondly, because if they fix their errors upfront then why waste a record in the database on their rough draft?

In my case, I do always fix my errors so this is not an issue. But what I think would be a superior approach is if the review page looked like the final product except with an eye-catching notice on top (and possibly bottom) to accept. And of course you would still add the controls to edit on the bottom so that could be accomplished on the same page.

Comment: Sounds like you'd be in favor of the new editor

Comment: @KevinB So this is perhaps a work in progress?

Comment: *"why waste a record in the database"*: There is still the 5 minute edit grace period (unless cut short by a comment)

Comment: "So this is perhaps a work in progress?" - not really. The new editor just inlines the text and preview (at least if you aren't using markdown mode). It isn't a proper page preview. Also wouldn't really help either way if it's built on the same preview system as the current (and only good) editor. There's a long-standing bug for tables where if you don't put an empty line between the table and the line above it, it renders fine in the preview, but not in the final product. Discrepancies like that alone are the main reason something like this would be useful, but it's possibly the only reason

Comment: I do agree with the idea of an improved preview, possibly on a separate page (or tab if going GitHub-style, but not important) as well, but the new editor is about as far as you get from even a basic start for something that might one day become that full page preview.

Comment: Reason 3: the moment the question is posted, the downvote and close vote buttons becomes clickable. It needs to shine before it is made available to curation, it is hard to recover from a question which is initially poorly received. Perhaps in this day and age it would even be prudent to say it is exceptionally hard. That alone really makes it important to have a proper review facility.